# What is the use for a late local variable?

Tags: dart

In Dart, we can declare a local variable without initializing it (and yes, it works with null safety too):

```dart
void conditionalInit(bool something) {
  int x;

  if (something) {
    x = 1;
    print(x); // OK
  }
}
```

If so, what is the added benefit of `late` modifier? The only one I can think of is that it silences the error of messy conditions like this:

```dart
void conditionalInit(bool something) {
  int x;

  if (something) {
    x = 1;
    print(x); // OK
  }

  if (something) {
    print(x); // This only compiles with late declaration
  }
}
```

But that should be avoided anyway.

So is there a legitimate use for local `late` variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible use for a local `late` variable:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> countToFive() {
  late StreamController<int> controller;

  controller = StreamController(
    onListen: () {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        controller.add(i + 1);
      }
      controller.close();
    },
  );
  
  return controller.stream;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await for (final number in countToFive()) {
    print(number);
  }
}
```

Because `controller` is `late` it is possible to reference `controller` within the `onListen` callback passed into the constructor of the `StreamController`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main use case is lazy initialization. A `late` variable will only be evaluated when it is accessed, which can be useful for costly computations which may not be required at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`late` is also useful to assign immutable final variables after initialization.

```
void conditionalInit(bool something) {
    late final int x;

    if (something) {
        x = 1;
        print(x); // OK
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Remove `late` from this, and it works the same. So what is the added benefit?

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables